# Angular 4 issue

Tags: angular

I have upgraded from Angular 2 latest version Angular 4  and when i try to run application and getting below warning message. Could someone advise on this.

```
node_modules/rxjs/Subject.d.ts(16,22): error TS2415: Class 'Subject<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable<T>'.
  Types of property 'lift' are incompatible.
    Type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<T>' is not assignable to type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<R>'.
      Type 'Observable<T>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<R>'.
        Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'R'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.d.ts(23,22): error TS2415: Class 'WebSocketSubject<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'AnonymousSubject<T>'.
  Types of property 'lift' are incompatible.
    Type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => WebSocketSubject<R>' is not assignable to type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<T>'.
      Type 'WebSocketSubject<R>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<T>'.
        Types of property 'operator' are incompatible.
          Type 'Operator<any, R>' is not assignable to type 'Operator<any, T>'.
            Type 'R' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

Comment: It looks like a known issue. There are several potential fixes here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17800

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue with typescript generic type checking.Revert your TypeScript version from 2.4.x to **2.3.2** .

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2701

Comment: Thanks , Below change fixed this issues on Angular. lift<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>): Observable<T>;
    lift<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>): Observable<R>; - on rxjs - subject.d.ts file